# get the view from the previous background?

Tags: android, view

If I am in `Activity 2`, and my previous Activity is `Activity 1`

How can I access the view the view of `Activity 1` in `Activity 2`

I have tried using `getCallingActivity();` but it returns `ComponentName`  whose view cant be accessed.

I also tried `Activity act = getParent();` but its returning `null`

Comment: You want to show some overlay or requirement need new activity to show old activity screenshot

Comment: I need the view of previous activity to convert it to bitmap.

Comment: In my knowledge its not possible. Is is ok if you pass it from previous to next activity

Comment: What data do you want to retrieve?